# webpack 2 with bower

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm currently working on project, which depends partialy on 'bower only' dependencies and I need somehow to add bower_components module to Webpack 2 bundle. How can I do it? Documentation from previous version doesn't work and bower-webpack-plugin is outdated. I'm using Webpack@2.2.1.
I added this code to webpack.config.js:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    modules: ['bower_components', 'node_modules']
}
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work.

Comment: how many modules are we talking here? you could just create an npm version of those modules, just export the module instead of attaching it to window.

Also you can try loading the bower components before your bundle, and refer to them globally.

Answer (score 0):

Use current version of [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules)

Correct resolving of path to `bower_components` with `path` module had helped me. Maybe it will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack2 can be used with bower with resolving options, you can read more here: https://gist.github.com/sokra/27b24881210b56bbaff7#resolving-options

A simple example of `webpack.config.js` resolving a `bower.json` file:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './file.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'my-first-webpack.bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [ "bower_components"],
        descriptionFiles: ["bower.json"]
    }
};
```